# Sonarqube not picking up both Kotlin and Java Coverage gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin, sonarqube, jacoco

This is **not** an android project with mixed source Java and Kotlin.
Eventhough many have had issues with coverage, kotlin and sonar. I didn't find one for this case.

Sonarqube is not picking up both Kotlin and Java Coverage generated by Jacoco:

- Gradle 4.8
- Java 1.8
- Kotlin 1.3.50

It gets the Java one, but all of the Kotlin classes gets ignored.
I have applied all required plugin in the gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin'

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your `jacocoTestReport` creates a xml report:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml {
            enabled true
        }
        xml.destination "build/reports/jacocoTestReport.xml"
    }
}
```

Then you will need to force those xml reports into sonar using the `xmlReportPaths` property in sonaqube for all projects.

You can see multiple paths here, that's in case you have multiple sub projects in your projects which also have mixed source Java / Kotlin.

```
sonarqube {
        properties {
            property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco"
            property("sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths", "../../build/reports/jacocoTestReport.xml,../build/reports/jacocoTestReport.xml")
        }
}
```

With that sonar will consider all the xml reports and generate the whole coverage.